# MirageJS Error response not causing an error

Tags: miragejs

Following the [docs](https://miragejs.com/docs/testing/application-tests/#testing-errors) I've set up this handler inside `routes()`:

```js
this.put(
  '/admin/features/error/environment/test',
  // @ts-ignore
  () => new Response(500, {}, { errors: ['The database went on vacation'] }),
);
```

Mirage does receive what I've set, sort of. Here is its response, from the browser console logs. Note that it's *not* an error although the 500 shows up in `_bodyInit`:

```json
{
    "type": "default",
    "status": 200,
    "ok": true,
    "statusText": "",
    "headers": {
        "map": {
            "content-type": "text/plain;charset=UTF-8"
        }
    },
    "url": "",
    "bodyUsed": false,
    "_bodyInit": 500,
    "_bodyText": "[object Number]"
}
```

Note that I need `ts-ignore` which is probably a clue. TS complains that `new Response` expects 0-2 arguments but got 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try importing the Mirage [Response](https://miragejs.com/api/classes/response/) class:

```js
import { Response } from 'miragejs';
```

Otherwise, `Response` refers to a [Fetch API Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object. This explains the type checking error and the unexpected behavior when calling the route.

After adding the import you can remove `@ts-ignore` and requests to the route should fail with status code 500.